# How do I group the records which have the same value for the "NAME" column?

Tags: excel

My data

```
NAME    QTY     LOCATION                
abc     3       a1                      
abc     3       a3                      
abc     3       a4                      
cdf     4       c5                               
cdf     4       c7                              
cdf     4       c1                              
cdf     4       c9                              
ghi     6       g12                             
ghi     6       g5                              
ghi     6       g17                             
ghi     6       g6                              
ghi     6       g89                             
ghi     6       g1
```

My desired result

```
NAME    QTY     LOCATION
abc     3       a1, a3, a4
cdf     4       c5, c7, c1, c9
ghi     6       g12, g5, g17, g6, g89, g1
```

How can I do this automatically using function(s) in Excel?

Comment: I think you need to explain the question a little more thoroughly and let us know what you have tried / looked into

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have created column C as "helper" to concatenate all relevant locations. Then I use column D to only show the last entry and "filter" the intermediate results.

As to the formulas:

- C1: `=B1`
- C2: `=IF(A2=A1,C1&", "&B2,B2)`
- C3: `=IF(A3=A2,C2&", "&B3,B3)`
- C4: etc...
- D1: `=IF(A1=A2,"",C1)`
- D2: etc...

[image]

Comment: Nice solution, I was thinking VBA, but it looks like this should do the job nicely.

Comment: it helps me with concantenate how can i automatically remove the duplicate i just want to retain the full concantenate value just like a1, a3, a4

Comment: What duplicates? In column D you have exactly that.

Comment: i appreciate your table i have created a table for my homework to thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

Makes a bit more sense with the formatting. Still a little extra info on where you want to copy to and from along with your attempts would be helpful.

I would suggest using VBA for this rather than formulas. If you don't know VBA, I would suggest recording a macro whilst going through the steps to copy the data manually. You can then view the code created by Excel and you will just need to replace absolute cell address references with a logical progression through relative addresses. Have a go at this, then fell free to ask if there are specifics you are stuck on.

Comment: How can i record a macro that you suggest chris? sorry am very little knowledge on this.

Comment: Okay, I could walk through this step by step, but I am sure there are many good tutorials on the web already. Google 'excel record a macro' or look in Excel help. I'm not meaning to be unhelpful, but I think you will actually learn more if you have a go at working things out yourself then post specific questions when you are stuck.

Comment: Let me know how you get on. Incase you did not find anything useful, this one seems to cover what you need to get started including how to view the code after: http://office.microsoft.com/en-gb/excel-help/create-or-delete-a-macro-HP010014111.aspx

Comment: Thanks for recommending recording macro it helps. By the way i try to use concantenate in the locations column manually location  by location so it takes time for me to finish the task. I tried IF function like this IF(c2:c13=match, concantenate, i got error and i'm stuck from here.

Comment: okay, @Jan has given a suggestion using formulas. May be worth giving this a try. When I had said to the steps manually to record the macro I had meant literally copying and pasting the data, but formulas would work too, you would just need to revise it in a different way once you had got the code.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `a1` is in C2, into D2 put:

`=IF(COLUMN()<COUNTIF($A:$A,$A2)+4,IF($A2=$A3,INDIRECT("$c"&ROW()+COLUMN()-4),""),"")`

1. Copy across and down to suit (say to ColumnZ).
2. Select entire sheet and copy Paste Special Values over the top.
3. In C2 put `=A1=A2` and copy down.
4. Filter of ColumnC to select TRUE and delete all visible rows.
5. In C1 put `=D1&","&E1&","&F1&","&G1&","&H1&","&I1` and so on to suit and copy down to suit.
6. Copy ColumnC and Paste Special Values over the top.
7. Replace `,,` with nothing in ColumnC.
8. Find somewhere in Row1 to put `=IF(RIGHT(C1,1)=",",LEFT(C1,LEN(C1)-1),C1)` and copy down.
9. Copy that column and Paste Special Values over the top of ColumnC.
10. Delete "that" column.
11. Add Column labels to suit.

Comment: I'll give it a try thanks and give you guys a result. hope i could exactly do what you have tried to explain using formula. i like this site very helpful.

Comment: i'm stuck with Filter of ColumnC to select TRUE and delete all visible rows. any help?

Answer (score 0):

This is somewhat possible without using VBA and using direct excel formulas.

I used your test data in columns A, B, and C and then I put the solution in Columns E-L here is a picture:

[image]
(This should work regardless of what order the data is in column A that's why I have a row misplaced)

The only *non* automated portion of this solution is that you must manually enter in the *name*'s in column E.  Whatever name you enter there the data to the right will automatically populate with the `QTY` and `Locations`.

This is slightly complicated but anyways here are the 3 formulas I used:

1. Column F: `=OFFSET($B$1,MATCH(E1,A:A,0),0)`
   This will grab the `QTY` value
2. Column G: `=OFFSET($C$1,MATCH($E1,$A$1:$A14,0)-1,0)`
   This will get the first `location` corresponding to the `name`
3. Column H-L: This formula you can put in column H and then fill across to the right.  It will grab the next location relative to the one to the left. `=IFERROR(OFFSET($C$1,MATCH($E1,INDIRECT("$A"&MATCH(G1,$C$1:$C14,0)+1&":$A$14"),0)+MATCH(G1,$C$1:$C14,0)-1,0),"")`

Here pictures to help:

Column F:
[image]

Column G:
[image]

Column H-L:
[image]

Comment: Glad to see other methods